# Rspec tests load error: cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm following a chapter on RSpec test, but I keep getting a `load error`.

It tells me first to create a new branch, then to make two new directories: `Models` and `Spec`. In these directories I am supposed to make two files; `models/entry.rb` and `spec/entry_spec.rb`. In the `spec/entry_spec.rb`, I'm supposed to enter this code:

```
require_relative '../models/entry'


RSpec.describe Entry do

end
```

Then in my `models/entry.rb` I am supposed to put this code:

```
class Entry

end
```

I am then supposed to run this terminal command:

```
$ rspec spec/entry_spec.rb
```

And get this result:

```
No examples found.

Finished in 0.00015 seconds (files took 0.1186 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures
```

But I'm always getting this load error though and I have no idea what it means

```
/Users/ethanfranson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)
    from /Users/ethanfranson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/ethanfranson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `block in requires='
    from /Users/ethanfranson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `each'
    from /Users/ethanfranson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `requires='
    from /Users/ethanfranson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:109:in `block in process_options_into'
    from /Users/ethanfranson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:108:in `each'
    from /Users/ethanfranson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:108:in `process_options_into'
    from /Users/ethanfranson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:21:in `configure'
    from /Users/ethanfranson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:105:in `setup'
    from /Users/ethanfranson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:92:in `run'
    from /Users/ethanfranson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:78:in `run'
    from /Users/ethanfranson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
    from /Users/ethanfranson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ethanfranson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/ethanfranson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/ethanfranson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/ethanfranson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

If any one would take the time to help me through What I may be doing wrong, I would really appreciate it. Sorry for the long winded question!

Comment: do you have the `spec_helper` file?

Comment: From which directory you are running the specs? root directory of app or spec directory?

Answer (score 4):

Double check that you are running `rspec spec/entry_spec.rb` from the root of app directory and not from within the `spec` directory.

Rspec adds the `spec` to the load path automatically. If you're already in the `spec` directory, `rspec` is going to add `spec/spec` to the load path instead.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer I was doing that on accident as well. So thank you for getting me one step closer I truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you have installed rspec-rails correctly:

```
rails g rspec:install
```

You don't need to require you model files or any other files in `/app` for that matter. They are autoloaded when you require `rails_helper`.

```
# spec/models/entry_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Entry do

end
```

RSpec can generate this spec for you with:

```
rails generate rspec:model entry
```

You should also setup the generators in your `config/application.rb`:

```
# ...
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec
end
```

That way when you run the regular rails generators RSpec such as `rails g model entry` it will create spec files for you as well.

Note that older versions of rspec-rails you would `require 'spec_helper'`, while in the current version you would use `require 'rails_helper'` since it splits the general RSpec config and the rails setup into two seperate files.

Comment: Hey max question. So I had someone clone my repo, and run the test on their computer, and the rspec test worked. However when I totally reinstalled, rvm, ruby, and rails, I still get the same error. Even trying what you suggested I get the same error. So do you think I could have something strange installed or not installed on my computer that prevents it from working? Ps. Thanks for your swift answer!